# How can I generate a random AES key and encrpyt/decrpyt a string using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, encryption, random, openssl, aes

I wan to create an application which generates random AES keys and encrypts or decrpyt a file or a string, but my method doesn't seem to work.
My code so far:

```
#include <openssl\aes.h>
#include <openssl\rand.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    unsigned char encrypted[512];
    unsigned char decrypted[512];

    unsigned char ckey[32];
    unsigned char iv[32];

    RAND_bytes(ckey, sizeof(ckey));
    RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv));

    AES_KEY key;
    FILE *out;
    out = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    const char test[] = "This is a test string";
    memcpy((char*)buffer, test, sizeof(buffer));

    AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 256, &key);
    AES_encrypt(buffer, encrypted, &key);

    fprintf(out, "%s\n\n", encrypted);

    AES_set_decrypt_key(ckey, 256, &key);
    AES_decrypt(encrypted, decrypted, &key);

    fprintf(out, "%s\n\n", decrypted);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But it generates a very strange output

```
LuÂ6(ö$Áü
žčLdqĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚThis is a test string

This is a test sĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚLuÂ6(ö$Áü
žčLdqĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚThis is a test string
```

I guess the test string shouldn't be there in the encrypted string.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `using namespace` is not C. Furthermore, you have to add error checking code to all the function calls.

Comment: To generate a random key, see [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) on the OpenSSL Wiki.